# CURAND running slower

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I am using CURAND to generate random numbers. I've created one `curandGenerator_t` to fill 3 arrays that are about 36 million random numbers. Each of those arrays has a different seed. The number generation is done inside a loop more or less like this:

```
curandGenerator_t randGenerator;
curandCreateGenerator(&randGenerator, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT);

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  curandSetStream(randGenerator, stream[0]);
  curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(randGenerator, seed[0]);
  curandGenerateUniformDouble(randGenerator, d_rv0, N);

  curandSetStream(randGenerator, stream[1]);
  curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(randGenerator, seed[1]);
  curandGenerateUniformDouble(randGenerator, d_rv1, N);

  curandSetStream(randGenerator, stream[2]);
  curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(randGenerator, seed[2]);
  curandGenerateUniformDouble(randGenerator, d_rv2, N);
}
```

It works fine as the results I'm getting are those expected but after profiling the app I realized that after some iterations of the loop the generation of the random numbers becomes slower. In the following image the blue-greenish item goes from 100 ms to 1 s.

Could someone explain if this is normal behavior of the random number generation?

Am I doing wrong generating random numbers with three different seeds and only one curandGenerator?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I can not re-create your profiling result, I don't get a slowing down effect in the loop.
2. I think you are using curand in a wrong way.

Generally, `curandSetSeed()` should be used only once after `curandCreateGenerator()`.

In your code you used it every time before generating random numbers, which will reset the generator to the same status w.r.t. the seed.
Although you fill `d_rv0` 100 times in your code, you are actually filling it with the same `N` random numbers each time.

If you intended to do so, you could generate `N` random number once, and then copy them 100 times.

If not, you could move `curandSetSeed()` out of the loop.

On the other hand, what is your purpose to use 3 seeds? If you just want get repeatable result from your program, 1 seed is enough. If you want to maintain separate random number streams, you need 3 generators each having 1 seed.

Comment: I tought that the generator saved the state even after changing the seed. And well I really need to have 3 different seeds for 3 different random streams. I'll take a look at it and see how it goes. If problem continues I will post again.

Comment: The problem was actually the `curandSetSeed()` I ran the same test and now there's no more slow down effect and in fact I got more speed up.